# How do I get my WPF Textbox to insert value in a variable and show it in a textarea?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I am quite new to WPF and I am wondering if someone could help me with this problem I am having. 
I am trying to get my TextBox to be able to give a value to a string variable.

This is the C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string player;

    public string PlayerName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Property); }
        set { SetValue(Property, value); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        player = user.Text;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PlayerName", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        this.PlayerName = player;
    }
}
```

And this is the Xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="memorytest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:memorytest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlayerName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,10,199.6,240" />
    <TextBox x:Name="user" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button Content="Click Me" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="Button_Click" />  
</Grid>
```

From other sources that I have read it seems that `player = user.Text;` is enough for that, but it won't display the variable in the textarea.

If someone could help me with this I would appreciate it.

Comment: `player = user.Text;` does not magically set the PlayerName property (if that is what you intended). Remove the `player` field and set `PlayerName = user.Text;`

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Text Binding of a TextBlock is pointless, because the Binding is OneWay. UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect on TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your answer! The program works now thank you!

Comment: Please note that instead of editing the solution into your question, you may better write (and later accept) a regular answer. You would thus indicate that the problem is solved.

Comment: Ok, I will do that in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Button Click handler should directly set the `PlayerName` property. The `player` field is not needed.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string PlayerName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Property); }
        set { SetValue(Property, value); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayerName = user.Text;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PlayerName", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```